# Does the Atomic Mass listed for each element on the periodic table reflect the relative abundances of their isotopes on Earth? Or in the Universe?

Tags: atoms, elements, periodic-table, mass-spectrometry, isotope

Somehow, I cannot find a site or book or paper explaining exactly how the average atomic masses for the elements on the periodic table are weighted....

I posted a question either here or on Physics S.E. about the possible inclusion of atomic mass defects and such on the calculations of average atomic mass, but apparently forgot to mention WHERE the isotopes are coming from...

I thought I had posted this question before on S.E. somewhere, or someone else had, but I cannot find it now....

If I had to guess, the isotope abundance ratios usually listed, and their weighted average that makes up an element's 'Atomic Mass', is based only on relative isotope abundances found on Earth (not including mantle or cores), and, maybe, the rest of the easily-visible Solar System...

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87929/is-atomic-weight-universal/87930#87930

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33056/is-the-relative-natural-abundance-of-isotopes-of-an-element-the-same-everywhere

Comment: Most of values are are for earth, or at least the portion of earth we can get our hands on.

Comment: I think is even more practical. Meaning that it reflects the isotopic composition of whatever (not enriched) chemical that can arrive at our bench / reaction vessels.